# Why is my symbol look so sparse in the pseudo code?

Tags: equations, pseudocode

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % 
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}  % Use Input in the format of Algorithm  
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}} % Use Output in the format of Algorithm  
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{xxx}
\label{alg:algorithm1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require
       $MRKG$,  ($NT$)
    \Ensure
      $D_n$;
    \State Load initial $MRKG$, New Task ($NT$);

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

As you can see here, the MRKG in my text is too sparse. Is there any way to make it not so sparse

[image]

When I follow samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz answer to do the modification

```
    \documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % 
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}  % Use Input in the format of Algorithm  
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}} % Use Output in the format of Algorithm  
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\RemovePeriod\caption{Stage 1 - Decision-making process for reconfiguration}
\label{alg:algorithm1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \If{\emph(BoP) $!=$ \emph{Null}}
    
    \State \emph{BoPs}.add(\emph{BoP})
   
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I found that when I use if-else, the character will not tilt.
[image]

Comment: Please note that you must only use one `\documentclass{...}`

Comment: Your use is incorrect. The first `\emph` doesn't have brackets for its argument, so it only takes the next token which is `(`. Instead, you should use `\emph{(BoP)}`.

Answer (score 3):

You set it in math mode. Math mode removes the normal kerning between letters. If you don't want this, don't put it in math mode.

If your goal is to have italic font, you could use `\emph{...}`, `\textit{...}` etc.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % 
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}  % Use Input in the format of Algorithm  
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}} % Use Output in the format of Algorithm  
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{xxx}
\label{alg:algorithm1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require
       \emph{MRKG},  (\emph{NT})
    \Ensure
      $D_n$;
    \State Load initial \emph{MRKG}, New Task (\emph{NT});

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I use \emph to represent D_n? I checked, it didn't work by myside

Comment: @James `_` is a character reserved for math mode. If you'd like a subscript in text mode, you need `D\textsubscript{n}`

Comment: I'd not use `\emph`, which is for *emphasis*, not for denoting some object that happens to be represented with italic type. Also `$D_n$` is definitely better than `\textit{D}\textsubscript{2}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider MRKG and NT to be math multiletter identifiers, use `\mathit`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}  % Use Input in the format of Algorithm  
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}} % Use Output in the format of Algorithm  

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{xxx}
\label{alg:algorithm1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require
       $\mathit{MRKG}$,  ($\mathit{NT}$)
    \Ensure
      $D_n$;
    \State Load initial $\mathit{MRKG}$, New Task ($\mathit{NT}$);

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]